# redux saga, throttle/debounce conditionally?

Tags: redux-saga

I'm logging banner impressions when it is visible on screen.

When a user scrolls, the same banner can be made visible multiple times in short time period.

And I'd like to prevent that.

On first thought, `throttle` is perfect way of preventing it.

But then when you have multiple banners in one page, `throttle` would not log the 2nd banner in screen if throttled.

So how can I throttle per key? (banner id as a key in this example)
ie, I want to throttle banner impression per banner_id. (it's like servers throttling api_endpoint access per api keys)

*EDIT*

One could think of creating `throttle` for each key, but wonder if it could take up too much resources?

I wonder how API libraries such as Django-rest-framework implements throttle per api key. I guess it could be totally different from what saga throttle does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using an expirable map

Things like `django-rest` use *expirable map* for throttling. An expirable *set* is sufficient for the task, too.

I cannot recommend an exact npm module for expirable map/set, unfortunately.

The *pseudocode*:

```js
function* throttlePerKey(pattern, selector, timeout, saga) {
  const set = new ExpirableSet({ expire: timeout })

  while(true) {
    const action = yield take(pattern)
    const id = selector(action)
    const throttled = set.has(id)
    if (throttled) {
      // Do nothing, action throttled
    } else {
      set.add(id)
      yield call(saga, action)
    }
  }
}
```

#### Using only redux-saga

We can emulate an expirable set with redux-saga, and get a purely redux-saga solution.

The code:

```js
function* throttlePerKey(pattern, selector, timeout, saga) {
  const set = new Set()

  while(true) {
    const action = yield take(pattern)
    const id = selector(action)
    const throttled = set.has(id)
    if (throttled) {
      // Do nothing, action throttled
    } else {
      set.add(id)
      // Expire items after timeout
      yield fork(function* () {
        yield delay(timeout)
        set.delete(id)
      })
      yield call(saga, action)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I 'm new to saga, but creating a channel for each key might drain computing resources?

Comment: @eugene `channel` seems to be [implemented](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/2aecdb310db8760ddd2c2513bf1cce7174c289d9/packages/core/src/internal/channel.js) as a publisher, and `take()` is a subscribe. Shouldn't consume too much memory.

Comment: I'll revisit this tomorrow, though. At least, channels should be destroyed when no banner impressions come in 5001 ms. And good idea about throttling entirely without saga features.

Comment: @eugene I added my basic idea of how to throttle per-key without `redux-saga`.

Comment: great, make sense, I guess one could just save the last insertion time as value of the map and test if key doesnt exist or value is 5000+ ms older than current time.

Answer (score 1):

Andrey's redux-saga solution is great. I modified it slightly to include a trailing call. For my use case (multiplayer document editor) I needed it to send data immediately after making a change but also at the end of the throttle delay so the most recent data was always sent.

```js
function* throttlePerKey(pattern, selector, timeout, saga) {
    const map = new Map()

    while (true) {
        const action = yield take(pattern)
        const id = selector(action)
        const throttled = map.has(id)
        if (throttled) {
            // track how many attempts there were
            map.set(id, map.get(id) + 1)
        } else {
            map.set(id, 1)
            // Expire items after timeout
            yield fork(function* () {
                yield delay(timeout)
                // Call at the end if there were multiple attempts
                if (map.get(id) > 1) {
                    yield call(saga, action)
                }
                map.delete(id)
            })
            // Call immediately on first attempt
            yield call(saga, action)
        }
    }
}
```