# Redux Saga - group similar (but not all) actions into takeLeading / takeLatest

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am currently using redux-saga on a project and I want to use it to also prevent requesting the same resource multiple times.

At the moment I have multiple components on the same page requesting a resource (i.e. dispatch `{types: "REQUEST_POST_COMMENTS", postId: <postIdHere>}`)

And I have this saga:

`export function* loadPostComments() {
  yield takeLatest("REQUEST_POST_COMMENTS", loadPostComments);
}`

My page dispatches the following actions at the same time:

- `{types: "REQUEST_POST_COMMENTS", postId: 123}`
- `{types: "REQUEST_POST_COMMENTS", postId: 321}`
- `{types: "REQUEST_POST_COMMENTS", postId: 123}`

And my goal is to for `loadPostComments` to be called twice, once for post 123 and one for post 321.

I have switched to `takeLeading` in the beta version - but this will only call `loadPostComments` once.

Is there any way to define a saga using a pattern but `takeLatest` to group them by the `action.type` value? Or any way of achieving something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My solution

You have to save encountered `postId`s and to them after:

```
function* watchRequestPostComments() {
  const encounteredPostIds = new Set()

  while(true) {
    const { postId } = yield take('REQUEST_POST_COMMENTS')
    if (!encounteredPostIds.has(postId) {
      yield fork(loadPostComments, postId)
    }
    encounteredPostIds.add(postId)
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

There doesn't seem to exist a particular redux-saga-esque way of doing this. In any case, you have to track these IDs.

I have answered a similar question about [throttling requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52839929/633969).

**P.S.:** This looks like an endless recursion. Must be an unintentional name clash:

```
export function* loadPostComments() {
  yield takeLatest("REQUEST_POST_COMMENTS", loadPostComments)
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this seems to do the trick. The endless recursion is indeed due to an unintentional name clash while writing the question :)