# "Splitting" an action channel/handler

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

Given this action type:

```
interface SaveFoo {
  type: 'SAVE_FOO'
  payload: {
    id: string
    value: number
  }
}
```

I want to create a saga that throttles the handler on a selective basis. So for example if the following actions were dispatched:

1. `{ type: 'SAVE_FOO', payload: { id: "a", value: 1 } }`
2. `{ type: 'SAVE_FOO', payload: { id: "b", value: 1 } }`
3. `{ type: 'SAVE_FOO', payload: { id: "a", value: 2 } }`
4. `{ type: 'SAVE_FOO', payload: { id: "a", value: 3 } }`

I want to kick off handlers for `1` and `2` (since they have different `id` properties), but assign `3` and `4` to a buffer until `1` has finished processing.

It feels like this should be quite a common use case but I couldn't find anything related. I have tried to hand-implement but I feel that there must be a better way:

```
  export function splitThrottle<T>(actionCreator: ActionCreator<T>, saga: (action: Action<T>) => SagaIterator, selector: (payload: T) => string) {
    const tasks: Record<string, Task> = {}
    const bufferLookup: Record<string, Buffer<Action<T>>> = {}

    function* queue(action: Action<T>, id: string) {
      try {
        yield call(saga, action)
      } catch (e) {
        // don't propagate
      }

      const next = bufferLookup[id].take()
      if (next) {
        tasks[id] = yield call(queue, next, id)
      } else {
        delete tasks[id]
      }
    }

    return function* () {
      while (true) {
        const action: Action<T> = yield take(actionCreator)
        const id = selector(action.payload)

        const existingTask = tasks[id]
        if (existingTask) {
          bufferLookup[id].put(action)
        } else {
          let buffer = bufferLookup[id]
          if (!buffer) {
            buffer = buffers.sliding(1)
            bufferLookup[id] = buffer
          }
          tasks[id] = yield fork(queue, action, id)
        }

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: NB question also asked as issue in github repo: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1688

Comment: I've [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52839929/633969) about a bit different kind of throttling. I'll post an answer if I get an idea of a simpler solution for your use case. Quite a common pattern, but everytime it's a bit different and there are no libraries for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I've implemented it. Pretty much the same solution with a bit different primitives:

```
export function* splitThrottle(pattern, saga, selector) {
  const channels = {}

  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(pattern)
    const id = selector(action)
    const { channel, justCreated } = obtainChannel(channels, id)

    yield put(channel, action)
    if (justCreated) {
      yield fork(processAllAndDelete, channels, id, saga)
    }
  }
}

function obtainChannel(channels, id) {
  let channel = channels[id]
  if (channel) {
    return { channel, justCreated: false }
  } else {
    channel = channels[id] = channel(buffers.expanding(1))
    return { channel, justCreated: true }
  }
}

function* processAllAndDelete(channels, id, saga) {
  const channel = channels[id]
  while (true) {
    const actions = yield flush(channel)
    if (!actions)
      break

    for (const action of actions) {
      yield call(saga, action)
    }
  }
  delete channels[id]
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of `yield put(channel, action)`